# Accessing HTML DOM elements in background on Ionic2

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2

With ionic2, I'm trying to implement a [Timer](http://jsbin.com/rihuhof/20/edit?html,css,js,output) as attached in the link on a sidemenu template. I have this implementation on one of the page how do we run this timer in background when trying to access a different page from the sidemenu. It works well for Ionic1 framework, but in ionic2 because of the navigation stack push & pop architecture the timer pauses when i leave the page and resumes when i enter back. So i'm not sure on how to implement this. Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks
Suresh

Comment: I have tried this one not too long ago and what I did is I created a `service` which is the one that created the timer and run it in the background. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to implement this one though so I would like to see what others have in mind for this.

Comment: Hi Adrian, Thanks for the update. Ya i was even thinking in a similar fashion. I have a question about the timer implementation in service.. i'm trying to use the timer functionality of observables from RxJs similar to the below link attached link below .. Do you have idea on how to start and pause the timer.If i start this service, i'm not sure how to stop it..[link]http://plnkr.co/edit/WUQJLO2b3o2w5zJ3DLkg?p=preview.

Comment: Sure, what I did is i was the service will expose a function in the service which initializes the timer, I didn't make a pausing feature though. I will make a plnkr for this when I get home for you to check. But for now you can dig on this repo of mine though its a bit cluttered. The provider: https://github.com/adrianonrails/philnits-reviewer/blob/master/app/providers/timer/timer.ts , consumer: https://github.com/adrianonrails/philnits-reviewer/blob/master/app/pages/question/question.ts

Comment: @adrian:Thanks for the link bro, this is my quick and dirty implementation which i did few hours before..[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/UMMlxW7M3iKpe53QOyFY?p=catalogue).  I also used soft states to control the timer. But not sure if this is recommendable.